Unable to connect to Neo4J database from Spring Boot application with credentials
I was able to connect to Neo4J database from Spring Boot Application without authentication.  I now enabled authentication and tries to connect, but it is complaining about
"TransactionSystemException: Could not open a new Neo4j session: Unsupported authentication token, scheme 'none' is only allowed when auth is disabled."
I have the following in my application.properties file.
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=myPassw@rd

I was able to connect to the Neo4J browser using the credentials. I did restart the DB and am still encountering this issue.  It appears spring boot is not using the username password in the properties file. Any help would be much appriciated.  Thanks.

Actually, it is my application.properties file should be:
spring.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
spring.neo4j.authentication.username=neo4j
spring.neo4j.authentication.password=myPassw@rd

Changing it fixed my problem.
